# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

This is my code:

```
class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self, inputFile): # initalizer / constructor
        #open input file and gets ready to parse it
        f = open(inputFile, "r")
        self.commands = list(f)
        f.close()
        print(self.commands)
        self.currentCommand = 0
        self.index = 0

    def hasMoreCommands(self):
        #are there any more commands in the input
        #returns boolean
        if (self.commands[self.currentCommand][self.index] == "\\")  and (self.commands[self.currentCommand][self.index+1] == "n"): # checks for "/n", alluding that the command has ended and we can advance to the next command
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def advance(self):
        #reads next command and makes it current command
        #called only if hasMoreCommands is true
        if self.hasMoreCommands():
            self.currentCommand += 1

    def commandType(self):
        #returns type of current command A_COMMAND, C_COMMAND, L_COMMAND
        #C A or L(psuedo command for (XxX))
        #dest=comp; jmp, @, ()
        self.type = self.commands[self.currentCommand][0]
        if self.type == "@":
            return "A_COMMAND"
        elif self.type == "(":
            return "L_COMMAND"
        else:
            return "C_COMMAND"

    def dest(self):
        #returns dest mnemoic of current C instruction - 8 Poss
        #called when command type is C
        #return string
        if (self.commandType() == "C_COMMAND") and ("=" in self.commands[self.currentCommand]):
                return self.commands[self.currentCommand][0:(self.commands[self.currentCommand].index("="))]

def main(inputFile):
    d = Parser(inputFile)
    d.commandType = "C_COMMAND"
    d.commands = ["D=A+2\\n", "AMD=A+5\\n"]
    d.currentCommand = 0
    print(d.dest())

main("/Users/user1/Desktop/filelocation/projects/06/add/add.asm")
```

The file in question:

```
// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org
// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"
// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.
// File name: projects/06/add/Add.asm

// Computes R0 = 2 + 3

@2
D=A
@3
D=D+A
@0
M=D
```

Error returned:

```
['// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org\n', '// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"\n', '// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.\n', '// File name: projects/06/add/Add.asm\n', '\n', '// Computes R0 = 2 + 3\n', '\n', '@2\n', 'D=A\n', '@3\n', 'D=D+A\n', '@0\n', 'M=D\n']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/filelocation/assembler.py", line 104, in <module>
    main("/Users/user1Desktop/filelocation/projects/06/add/add.asm")
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/filelocation/assembler.py", line 99, in main
    print(d.dest())
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/filelocation/assembler.py", line 50, in dest
    if (self.commandType() == "C_COMMAND") and ("=" in self.commands[self.currentCommand]):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I was attempting to test dest.
This is a part of the Nand 2 Tetris / Elements of Computing Systems curriculum at Chapter 6.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: `d.commandType = "C_COMMAND"`... You overwrote the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main, you are replacing the method `def commandType(self)` with `d.commandType = "C_COMMAND"`, which is a `str` and therefore cannot be called like a method.

Comment: If this solves your problem, accepting the answer would be great.

Comment: It says I need to wait 8 minutes. I will do so after the alloted period of time.

Answer (score 0):

For your class....

```
class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self, inputFile): # initalizer / constructor
        #open input file and gets ready to parse it
        f = open(inputFile, "r")
        self.commands = list(f)
        f.close()
```

You already set `self.commands` **from the file**

<sub>And note: `index` and `currentCommand` appear to serve the exact same purpose</sub>

Your function uses that list.

```
def commandType(self):
    #returns type of current command A_COMMAND, C_COMMAND, L_COMMAND
    #C A or L(psuedo command for (XxX))
    #dest=comp; jmp, @, ()
    self.type = self.commands[self.currentCommand][0]
```

Therefore, you do not need these lines

```
def main(inputFile):
    d = Parser(inputFile)
    # d.commandType = "C_COMMAND"
    # d.commands = ["D=A+2\\n", "AMD=A+5\\n"]
    # d.currentCommand = 0
```

So you only need this `main` assuming the input file is correct.

```
def main(inputFile):
    d = Parser(inputFile)
    print(d.dest())
```

---

Your error is that `d.commandType = "C_COMMAND"` cannot be "called" by `"C_COMMAND()"`, (i.e. `d.commandType()`)